# Reading on socket with EOT, SOH, STX among other characters

Tags: ruby, regex, sockets, celluloid

I'm using Celluloid IO to read from sockets. The incoming message has the following syntax

sometextsometextsometext

where

```
SOH = Hex 1
FS  = Hex 1C
STX = Hex 2
ETX = Hex 3
EOT = Hex 4
```

My read code is something like this -

```
message = ""
begin
  data = socket.readpartial(4096)
  message << data
end until message =~ /not sure what goes here/
```

I'm looking for a reliable way to read from the socket until EOT. Once the message is read, i'll regex out the relevant sections.

Some guidance on detecting the above mentioned hex characters in socket read stream and in regex would be very helpful. Guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And this does the trick for me thanks

```
def parse(message)
  if message =~ /\001(.*)\01C(.*)\002(.*)\003\004/
    return ($1,$2,$3)
  end
end

def read_until_eot(socket)
  eot_found = false
  message = ''
  begin
    data = socket.read()
    eot_found = !!data['\004']
    message << data
  end until eot_found
  message.chomp!
end

def handle_connection(socket)
  # read from socket until EOT
  message = read_until_eot(socket) # <-- need help with
  if (origin,target,payload) = parse(message) #message can be parsed
    #   process message
    output_message = process(payload)
  end
  # write to socket
  socket.write output_message
  # close socket
  socket.close
end
```